# Joomla 3 display articles of subcategories

Tags: joomla3.0

I am building a website with Joomla 3.2 Framework and I am faced to situation where I do not undertand how to bypass.
I have this architecture of categories :

```
Cat 1
  |- Sub cat1
  |- Sub cat2
```

In Sub cat1 I have 5 articles.
In Sub cat2 I have 3 articles.
With a menu, I can display all articles of Sub cat1 or 2.
But now, I want to display all articles of sub cat1 and 2 in a single page with a menu.
What I thought first was that I can make a menu to point on Cat 1 and display all article of Sub cat1 and2. I did it and it is not working.
Anyone knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by doing as below:

- Go to Menu Manager from Joomla Admin and open a menu items list of menu where you can create link of page for above requirements.
- Now, Click "New" button to create a new Joomla Menu Item for menu. Wait while new menu item form opens.
- After loading new menu item form, click on blue "Select" button on right side of "Menu Item Type* " field of form. Here you can have a modal box of various options to choose.
- OK, now Expand section of " Articles " by pressing over it. By doing this, you can see list of items in which you can find "Category Blog" item. Yes, just click on this and you will be shown some other fields in existing form.
- After doing this, you need to choose "Cat 1" (as per mentioned in your question) from "Choose a category *" dropdown.
- Now, from same form click on "Blog Layout" tab and select "All" for "Include Subcategories" drop-down field.
- Just add Title and suitable alias to your new Joomla Menu Item for this category page and save the menu item.

This will load articles from Sub-Categories also.
let me know if it doesn't work Or if other problem...

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can see all the settings and the live results on the image. Remember to set # Link to 0 - the number of items that are not shown, but only linked to.

[image]